# MSE of filtered noisy signal - Derivation

Tags: expected-value, filter, mse

I'm working on understanding the derivation of the optimal time constant for filters based on minimizing mean squared error. Unfortunately the text made a big jump between steps and lost me.

Here's part of the derivation:

$$
\theta_g = \theta +\sigma_g^2 +B_g
$$
Where $\theta$ is the actual value, and $\theta_g$ is the input signal with variance $\sigma_g^2$ and constant bias B_g. Note that $\sigma_g^2$ is gaussian white noise.

This signal is sent through a high pass filter, which results in scaling of magnitude
$$
f(\omega)=\frac{\tau}{\sqrt{\tau^2\omega^2+1}}
$$
$$
\hat\theta = f(\omega)*\theta_g
$$

The text then goes on to calculate the mean square error for this estimator. Here's where I got lost:
$$
E(e_{\sigma_g}^2) = \frac{\sigma_g^2}{2\pi}*\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! f(\omega)^2 \, \mathrm{d} \omega = \frac{\tau\sigma_g^2}{2}
$$
$$
E(e_{B_g}^2) = \tau^2*B_g
$$
$$
E(e_{total}^2) = \frac{\tau\sigma_g^2}{2} + \tau^2*B_g
$$

From what I can see, the integral sums all the magnitudes squared. $2\pi$ is the range of values $\theta$ can take on. I'm just not sure why the equations are set up this way.

Why is the function squared in the integral, and why is $2\pi$ in the denominator? And how was $E(e_{B_g}^2)$ calculated? Could anyone help me out here?